# Number of parents and children of a commit in GIT

Tags: git

Please correct me if I am wrong:

The number of parents of a commit can be:

- 0 - only for the initial commit in the REPO
- 1 - for a simple commit on some branch
- 2 - for a merge commit

The number of parents cannot be more than 2.

The number of children can be any non-negative number.

- Zero for commit on the tip of one or more branches
- One for simple commit on a branch
- Any value greater than one if several branches were created out of a commit and these branches have commits.

Comment: For a commit, the number of its parents is fixed, and the number of its children is unpredictable.

Comment: Note that the fact that the number of parents and children of any node can be any nonnegative integer, plus the fact that the number of parents of a node is fixed and the parents of an existing node exist, means that the commit graph is a simple Directed Acyclic Graph that can be added-to but never otherwise changed. (I'm glossing over the effect of `git gc` on *unreachable* nodes here, on purpose.)

Comment: No more than 2 parents? [Seems like](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/blog/2017/the-biggest-and-weirdest-commits-in-linux-kernel-git-history) Linux history begs to differ. (Quote: "*Christ, that's not an octopus, that's a Cthulhu merge*")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of parents can be any non-negative number, see the [`octopus`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-octopus) strat, and a 0-parent commit can be added at any time, though there's legitimate debate over that usage such debates tend to be settled in favor of usefulness.